# Bootstrap tabs to move between tabs through buttons Prev/next

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

"Bootstrap tabs to move between tabs through buttons Prev/next."

I have a javascript function that let me go one tab next:

```
$(".btn-style").click
(
    function()
    {
        $('.nav-tabs li:eq(1) a').tab('show');

        $("[class='btn btn-large btn-block btn-success disabled']").removeClass("btn btn-large btn-block btn-success disabled");
        $('.nav-tabs li:eq(1) a').addClass("btn btn-large btn-block btn-success disabled");
    }
);
```

my html:

```
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="width: 1050px">
                                <li><a href="#Race" class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-success disabled" data-toggle="tab">Race</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#Ace" data-toggle="tab">Ace</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#Deep" data-toggle="tab">Deep</a></li>

                        </ul>


                                <div class="tab-content">


                                        <!-- Race -->
                                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="Race">
                                                     <button class="btn-style" type="submit">Prev</button>
                                                     <button class="btn-style" type="submit">Next</button>

                                         </div>

                                        <!-- ACE -->
                                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="Ace">
                                                     <button class="btn-style" type="submit">Prev</button>
                                                     <button class="btn-style" type="submit">Next</button>

                                        </div>


                                </div>
```

I need a javascript or jquery function through which i can go through all my tabs one by one on clicking a button in their respective tabs. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: You can add a custom attribute to all your tab items say custom attribute with Name tabIdentifier = "tab" + some enumerator. so you can have a generic javascript method which will be fired on click of the button, that will retrieve the button's wrapping tab i.e. div read this custom attribute and then based on the enumerator you can set the previous or next tab active by subtracting or adding the enumerator by one and selecting the required tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call this common function on Next and previous  buttons on `Click` event

```
$('#nxt').on('click', function () {
   moveTab("Next");
});
$('#prv').on('click', function () {
   moveTab("Previous");
});


function moveTab(nextOrPrev) {
   alert(nextOrPrev);
   var currentTab = "";
   $('.nav-tabs li').each(function () {
      if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        currentTab = $(this);
      }
   });

   if (nextOrPrev == "Next") {
      if (currentTab.next().length) 
      {
         currentTab.removeClass('active');
         currentTab.next().addClass('active');}
      else {} // do nothing for now

    } else {
      if (currentTab.prev().length) 
      {
        currentTab.removeClass('active');
        currentTab.prev().addClass('active');
      }
      else {} //do nothing for now 
    }
  }
```

LIVE DEMO @ http://jsfiddle.net/R3mCY/50/

*Note:I have removed the click events callback added for next and previous button from the html, instead attached a callback function for click event for both buttons in Jquery itself*

Happy Coding :)

Comment: @user3193259: there were few syntax in the code,i`ve corrected them now.

Comment: i will try now and will tell you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/R3mCY/56/ 

can u modified this @dreamweiver. only above tabs are changing but not the content. 

var i = 1;
$('.nav-tabs li:eq(i) a').tab('show');
i++;

// i tried this but its not working

Comment: Ya sure no probs, will let u know once fixed.

Comment: Thanks, had to add this but thought I would google before hand, so you just saved me the hassle:)

Answer (score 1):

I'd tackle it like this:

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="width: 1050px">
    <li class="active"><a href="#Race" data-toggle="tab">Race</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#Ace" data-toggle="tab">Ace</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#Deep" data-toggle="tab">Deep</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <!-- Race -->
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="Race">
        <button class="btn-style" type="submit">Prev</button>
        <button class="btn-style" type="submit">Next</button>
    </div>
    <!-- ACE -->
    <div class="tab-pane" id="Ace">
        <button class="btn-style" type="submit">Prev</button>
        <button class="btn-style" type="submit">Next</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And JS:

```
$(".btn-style").click(function () {
    var target = $(".nav-tabs li.active");
    var sibbling;
    if ($(this).text() === "Next") {
        sibbling = target.next();
    } else {
        sibbling = target.prev();
    }
    if (sibbling.is("li")) {
        sibbling.children("a").tab("show");
    }
});
```

I grabbed the normal styling from http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs cause I didn't feel like working with all the button classes.

Comment: @user3193259 it works for me, see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RRWyf/. Maybe I've misinterpreted something?

Comment: yeah thankyou its working. but i have the same problem only above tabs are changing but not the content.

Comment: @user3193259 My bad, looking at the docs you actually shouldn't remove / add the active class yourself. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RRWyf/1/

Comment: just perfect. thankyou so much. the only problem i have now is how to change the class which is in my case "btn btn-large btn-block btn-success disabled"

i tried this

        $("[class='btn btn-large btn-block btn-success disabled']").removeClass("btn btn-large btn-block btn-success disabled");
        $(this).sibbling("li").addClass("btn btn-large btn-block btn-success disabled");

first line remove the css from the previous tab but sencond line didnot add the css onto the next tab.

Answer (score 0):

// This is the final solution **(Thanks to: gpgekko and dreamweiver)**

```
<!-- Move to other tabs by clicking on the button -->
<script>
$(".a-btn-text").click(function ()
  { 
    var target = $(".nav-tabs li.active");
    var sibbling;

    if ($(this).text() === "Next")
    {
        sibbling = target.next();
    }

    else
    {
        sibbling = target.prev();
    }

    if (sibbling.is("li"))
    {
        sibbling.children("a").tab("show");
        $("[class='btn btn-large btn-block btn-success disabled']").removeClass("btn btn-large btn-block btn-success disabled");
        sibbling.children("a").addClass("btn btn-large btn-block btn-success disabled");
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is thing you want.

**JS**

```
$('.continue').click(function(){
  $('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});
$('.back').click(function(){
  $('.nav-tabs > .active').prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.tabs-wrap {
    margin-top: 40px;
}
.tab-content .tab-pane {
    padding: 20px 0;
}
```

**Finally HTML**

```
<div class="container tabs-wrap">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active">
      <a href="#billing" aria-controls="billing" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">Billing Address</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#shipping" aria-controls="shipping" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Delivery Address</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#review" aria-controls="review" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Review &amp; Payment</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

<div class="tab-content">

  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="billing">
    <h3 class="">Billing Address</h3>
    <p>Billing Address Form</p>
    <a class="btn btn-primary continue">Continue</a>
  </div>

  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="shipping">
    <h3 class="">Shipping Address</h3>
    <p>Shipping Address Form</p>
    <a class="btn btn-primary back">Go Back</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary continue">Continue</a>
  </div>

  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="review">
    <h3 class="">Review &amp; Place Order</h3>
    <p>Review &amp; Payment Tab</p>
    <a class="btn btn-primary back">Go Back</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary continue">Place Order</a>
  </div>
</div></div>


            <div id="push"></div>
```

From http://www.bootply.com/fGvD5eB3Ms