# Wrap bootstrap nav tab into previous / next button

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [Nav tab](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav) from bootstrap but when I have multiple tabs this will give me this result :

[image]

When I resize my browser I can get more than 10 rows of tab... There is a way to wrap the tabs below the first line into a previous / next button or something like this ?

Comment: Do you mean something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21309773/bootstrap-tabs-to-move-between-tabs-through-buttons-prev-next.

Comment: This is just the events for next / previous. That I need is the CSS side. How to wrap the tabs into previous / next buttons as a pagination table